# css transform matrix get left or top?

Tags: javascript

Calculation left or top ?

```
 <div style="width:100px;height:50px;"></div>
 div.style.transform = `rotateZ(45deg)`
 // 获取矩阵
 let transform = window.getComputedStyle(div)['transform'],
     matrix = transform.slice(7, -1).split(',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get matrix of a div with javascript, you can try to these

```
let style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
let transform = style.transform;
let matrix = transform.replace('matrix(', '').replace(')','').split(',')
```